# Daemon Threads in java and its process space

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a main application which creates two threads viz A and B. Thread A is user thread and thread B  is daemon. A finishes the job and hence the JVM exits but Thread B is still running. Since Threads A and B are created in the JVM space, and JVM has exited since all the user threads have completed execution, where Thread B execute ? In which process space does it execute?

Comment: Thread B dies with the JVM, it doesn't continue to run.

Comment: But My assumption is that the JVM exits when all the user threads completes execution. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why do you think "Thread B is still running" if you see that JVM has exited?

Comment: I've designed it to be run for more than a day..

Comment: The JVM dies when all non-daemon threads have finished. The daemon threads are killed at that point, that's the whole point of daemon threads. If you don't want that to happen, you need to keep at least one non-daemon thread alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "daemon" thread is intended to provide a general service in the background as long as the program is running, but is not part of the essence of the program. Thus, when all of the non-daemon threads complete, the program is terminated "abruptly", killing all daemon threads in the process.

So as soon as all non-daemon exits, the JVM shuts down all the daemons immediately, without any of the formalities you might have come to expect (Not even Finally). Because you cannot shut daemons down in a nice fashion, they are rarely a good idea.

Non-daemon Executors are generally a better approach, since all the tasks controlled by an Executor can be shut down at once.

Now Coming to your particular scenario.

> A finishes the job and hence the JVM exits but Thread B is still
>   running- This Assumption is wrong B is not running

where Thread B execute ? In which process space does it execute?

> B Will be terminated "abruptly" as soon as A is finished so it
>   not in execution now and hence no question of process space.

Comment: I've read in few blogs that JVM exists once all the user threads are completed successfully, without unwinding the stacksof the daemon thread. Is that means those daemon threads are killed once all the user threads are completed.

Comment: @wekselva Yes its true as generally we use term user threads for Non-daemon Threads.Not sure why it was not clear from my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Vipin. It was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Daemon threads are used in background task for example GC or custom use case.
And the purpose of daemon threads is to serve User threads and once there is no user threads running and program exit then no use of daemon threads